# change image background in a moreNavigationController navigationBar ios 5

Tags: ios, background, customization, navigationcontroller, navigationbar

this is the appdelegate:

```
  UINavigationController *moreController = _tbc.moreNavigationController;
    moreController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]; 
    [image drawInRect:rect];



    /*    UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)moreController.topViewController.view;
     //   [moreTableView initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
     [moreTableView setBackgroundColor:BACKGROUNDCOLOUR];*/
```

it works only if i change the background color, but how can I do to replace the background with an image?

---

[ S O L V E D ]

Now its works!!

`[moreController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: Find the answer here on SO


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929987/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-with-image-on-some-views-but-not-all

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works!!! [moreController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this does work and has been implemented `[navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Also take a look into the Apple Docs on this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html  It gives further explanation on what and how to customise UINavigationBar. Target needs to be iOS5+

Comment: @Luca Zap. No problem, happy to help!!